# compact composition of linear and nonlinear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X $ be Hilbert space, and $X'$ be its dual. Assume, $T:X' \rightarrow X$ is linear, continuous and $N: X \rightarrow X'$ is nonlinear, continuous and uniformly bounded. Does it imply that $T \circ N : X \rightarrow X$ is compact?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean for a nonlinear function to be compact?

Comment: @copper.hat Same as for linear: bounded sets are mapped to sets with compact closure. This property appears in [Schauder's fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed_point_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless $X$ is finite dimensional. Identify $X$ with its dual $X'$. Take $T$ to be the identity and $N(x)=x$ if $\|x\|\leq 1$ and $N(x)=x/\|x\|$ otherwise. Then, $N$ is "nonlinear", continuous and uniformly bounded and the composition $x\mapsto T(N(x))$ is not compact: $TN$ maps the unit ball in $X$ onto itself and this is not compact unless $X$ is finite dimensional.